# SQL getting invalid relational operator and I want this to be used in a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
select 
    size_desc 
from 
    ODS_INPT_ITEM_MASTER  
group BY 
    CREATE_DATE_TIME
having 
    max(CREATE_DATE_TIME)
```

Comment: please tag the rdbms you are using,

Comment: please improve your question by looking at here :https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I am using oracle 11 g

Comment: please look into the above link and improve the question

Answer (score 0):

The having clause needs to have some operator that lets SQL know how to filter like so :

```
having max(CREATE_DATE_TIME) > '2016-07-01'
```

**Edit :**

Based on your comment ... this is how you would get the max date for each  size_desc

```
select size_desc, max(CREATE_DATE_TIME) as MaxDate
from ODS_INPT_ITEM_MASTERsize_desc
group by size_desc
```

Comment: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: @Arun see the edit above ... what is your requirement ? what do you expect from that query ?

Comment: I am excepting the latest record of size_desc and I will be using that in a subquery

Comment: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"

Comment: Well yes but you need to know the syntax and understand what you are doing :)